# Use local dependencies and remote

Tags: maven

I have 2 project. one uses local dependencies.

This is the `settings.xml` content.

```
<localRepository>C:/sales/dependency/repository</localRepository>
<interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>
<usePluginRegistry>true</usePluginRegistry>
<offline>true</offline>
```

Second one uses remote (my own Nexus repo) server.

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://172.19.128.12:8090/repository/salesgroup</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

I am going to merge these two projects. I cannot upload my local dependencies to Nexus. So, I have to use both in my project.  In that case, how should the `settings.xml` file look like.

Answer (score 0):

Instead if adding you nexus repository as mirror add both you nexus and local repository as repository in a profile in `~/.m2/settings.xml` as below.

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

    ...    

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>maven-repositories</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>local</id>
                    <name>Local</name>
                    <url>file:///C:/sales/dependency/repository</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>nexus</id>
                    <name>Nexus Repository</name>
                    <url>http://172.19.128.12:8090/repository/salesgroup</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>maven-repositories</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I recommend:

In `~/.m2/settings.xml`

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository -->
  <localRepository>C:/sales/dependency/repository</localRepository>

  ...

</settings>
```

This will make `C:/sales/dependency/repository` directory as local repository at user level for all maven projects.

Now, when you say combining two project, there are two possibility as below:

- You will have single pom and src folder merged
- You will have parent pom and these two projects will be modules of it.

In both cases, you can just define `<repositories>` under single pom / parent pom file of your combined project. Thus this/these project/s will use the your internal repository to resolve the dependencies which are not in `local` repository.

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

For more details you can read [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) more!